# Технические детали наследования

Tags: наследование, c#, .net

Господа, можно, хотя бы вкратце пояснить тех. сторону наследования в с#. Я имею в виду , что конкретно происходит при наследовании. Просто копируется код от базового к потомку, или внутри потомка создается объект базового с прямым доступом к открытым членам базового класса, или еще какой-то вариант ?? Спасибо.

ПС. гугл не помог, так как разные сайты и ведиоуроки противоречат сами себе. Кто говорит, что класс потомок как бы забирает себе члены базового класса, кто говорит, что в потомке создается объект базового класса с возможностью прямого доступа, кто вообще магию приплетаетю Спасибо

Comment: >кто вообще магию приплетаетю

а можно пример источника, где наследование объясняется с помощью магии?

Comment: Ну это я образно сказал ))) Просто в некоторых источниках, даже в том же самом Шилдте встречается противоречие самому себе. Потому это я назвал магией

Comment: @polyakov_s: Весь Шилдт — противоречие самому себе. Читайте нормальные книги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, вам как программисту не нужно об этом беспокоиться. Конкретные детали реализации не так важны, важно лишь то, как код исполняется.

Фактически, судя по всему, (невиртуальные) методы создаются отдельно от объектов, во время компиляции, а возможность класса вызвать метод по имени определяется лишь таблицами видимости у компилятора. При этом в таблицы видимости производного класса компилятором включаются таблицы базового класса (чтобы гарантировать выполнение стандарта).

По виртуальным методам картинка чуть-чуть отличается. При компиляции вызова виртуального метода компилятор не знает, какой метод будет вызван фактически, поэтому вводится дополнительный уровень косвенности: таблица виртуальных методов. Каждому виртуальному методу соответствует индекс в таблице, а реальная таблица зависит от реального типа объекта (одна на тип), и привязывается к объекту во время выполнения конструктора.

С данными всё по-другому: наследование данных обозначает, что экземпляр объекта требует при создании память как для своих полей, так и для полей класса-предка. Этот размер, понятно, константа для каждого данного класса, и определяется во время компиляции.

Всё это в принципе лишь пример возможной реализации. Поскольку стандарт не требует конкретной реализации наследования, настоящая реализация может быть любой. Например, теоретически возможно «прикреплять» методы к объекту по именам в рантайме (наподобие того, как это делает `ExpandoObject`).

Answer (score 3):

Единственное, что здесь стоит обязательно знать, это то, что при  наследовании класс-потомок получает все члены базового класса за исключением конструкторов (в том числе статических) и деструкторов). Как именно это реализуется на практике - дело в общем-то десятое и особого значения не имеет (надо полагать, что в различных реализациях языка это теоретически может быть выполнено различными способами). Если обратить внимание на спецификацию языка (пункт 1.6.4) то там ничего не говорится о конкретной реализации этого механизма, а лишь упоминается вышесказанное:

> Inheritance means that a class implicity contains all members of its base class, except for the instance and static constructors, and the destructors of the base class.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но тут вот еще вопрос появился. Получается, что ключевое слово base.имя_члена обращается к члену в базовом классе или члену-копии базового класса внутри потомка?? И правильно ли я понял, что при наследовании потомок забирает у базового код, а не базовый его впихивает потомку. Спасибо.

Comment: если вы используете слово base для получения доступа к членам базового класса, то это означает, что вы обращаетесь к членам именно этого экземпляра класса-потомка, которые унаследованы от класса-родителя. Именно к членам потомка, а не к неким  членам какого-то там экземпляра класса-предка.

>И правильно ли я понял, что при наследовании потомок забирает у базового код, а не базовый его впихивает потомку

звучит как-то туманно. Постарайтесь иззъясняться более конкретно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !! Со вторым вопросом у меня такая дилема: то ли класс потомок забирает код у родителя, то ли родитель инициализирует свои поля и отдает потомку при наследовании. Например у родителя есть конструктор с параметрами. Потомок вызывает этот конструктор и родитель инициализирует свои поля. Но что потом ?? После того как родитель проинициализировался он передает эти проинициализированные значения потомку или их потомок сам себе забирает ?? Вопрос че-то не получается сформулировать людским языком. Спасибо

Comment: В каком смысле «забирает код»? Конструктор — функция, просто он в начале запускает на выполнение другую функцию: конструктор базового класса. (Почти в начале.)

Comment: >После того как родитель проинициализировался он передает эти проинициализированные значения потомку или их потомок сам себе забирает ?? 

Потомок ничего никуда не "забирает". Потому что нет никакого отдельного родительского объекта - все данные, которые определены в предке (на уровне декларации), изначально содержатся в потомке. То есть, если у нас объявлены предок P1 и потомок P2, и мы создаём объект типа P2, это не значит, что в скомпилированной программе будет создано 2 объекта, которые между собой как-то общаются.

Comment: Спасибо, прояснилось !!!